# Error: table book has 4 columns but 5 values were supplied

Tags: python

Getting error:

"insert
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO book VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?)" ,(title,author,year,isbn))
sqlite3.OperationalError: table book has 4 columns but 5 values were supplied"

while running below code, i want to id column with primary key integer while inserting data in table in database.

```
import sqlite3

def connect():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title text, author text, year integer, isbn integer)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def insert(title,author,year,isbn):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO book VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?)" ,(title,author,year,isbn))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

why you put `NULL` in `book VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?)` ? try without `NULL`

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO book VALUES (?,?,?,?)" ,(title,author,year,isbn))
```

Comment: Thanks! Zimdero, Now i am getting this error--  in insert
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO book VALUES (?,?,?,?)" ,(title,author,year,isbn,))
sqlite3.IntegrityError: datatype mismatch

Comment: I am trying to add this-

insert("def","abc",2018,182829191)

Comment: You've got an extra trailing comma inside that tuple. Is that intentional? Either way, I'd then check the parameters you're passing in. Eg is the ISBN _really_ an integer? Integers only hold a max value of `2147483647`

Comment: Zimdero, I am sorry , if i sound stupid, i am still learning python..this is where i have defined the types of parameters...cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title text, author text, year integer, isbn integer)")...and these are the parameters i am passing in the function while inserting data...insert("def","abc",2018,182829)..as per this isbn is a integer

Comment: maybe `182829` is BIGDATA for type `integer` try to put simple `1` same error?

Comment: @zimdero..Could this be about version of Python i am using or version SQlite3

Comment: @zimdero..It is working now...with primary key and NULL value..all i had to do was to change the name of the table and create a new table...may be entry already existing was the issue..thanks! for your time and effort..appreciate it..